# Does the DataGridView differentiate between upper and lower cases in column names?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have been messing with DataGridViews over the past weeks and noticed something strange happening.
If a column is named "A" and another column is named "a", sorting one will automatically sort by the other:

Unsorted:
[image: Unsorted DataGridView]

Sorted by clicking on "A" once:
[image: Sorted DataGridView by one click on column "A"]

As you can see, after clicking the capitalized "A" once, the lower case "a" gets sorted the same way. Having these columns be named in this way is crucial to my app so simply changing the name is not an option. Does anyone know how this works exactly and perhaps a workaround?

**Edit**:
This also happens when the values in the columns are not the same. Even though the values in the DataSource are different, the values shows on the DataGridView are the same in both columns:

The DataSource

[image: DataSource of the table]

The DataGridView of **the same** table:

[image: DataGridView showing the values differing]
Thanks in advance,

Ayden

Comment: Sorting is related to the contents not to the columns names. Change the contents of both columns `A` and `a` and do a test.

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-sorting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) if you need custom sorting.

Comment: @JQSOFT This happens to every table with capitals and lower cases as column names. Even if the DataSource is different, the values in both columns will be the same. As I am typing this, it sounds like a good thing to mention in the question. I will edit it.